# Utility Control Point enrollment fails SQL Server 2008 R2 enterprise

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have created a Utility Control Point on one instance of SQL Server 2008 R2 Enterprise.  I have 2 other SQL Server instances that are already pushing data to a management warehouse database on the UCP server (separate database). I would like to enroll those 2 servers that are already part of an MDW to the UCP, however when I go through the enrollment process it validates successfully, but during the enrollment's final stage it throws an error during the enrolling the instance step:

> An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. Could not obtain information about Windows NT group/user 'domain\user', error code 0x5. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 15404)

The `'domain\user'` that it lists in the error message is the AD domain service account on the target server to be enrolled.  All 3 of these servers are on the same domain, the SQL Server Agent Service accounts are different for each server. When going through the enrollment set up I have connected to the instance with a domain account and the `sa` account and tried different service accounts none of which seem to work.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I have had similar difficulties when using both the MDW and UCP and pushing the data to separate database's. Try cleaning up data collection or just removing it and re-enrolling. All else fails burn it down and use a single database for MDW and UCP data